# JSON data from factory not being fetched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my controller:

```
 mainApp.controller('recordController', [ '$scope', 'record', 'recordSlides', function($scope, record, recordSlides) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page page-record';
    record.success(function(data){
        $scope.tracks = data;
    });

    $scope.myInterval = 3000;
    recordSlides.success(function(data){
        $scope.slides = data;
    });
        /*$scope.slides=[
            {
                "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
            },
            {
                "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food"
            }
        ]*/}])
```

These are the factories I am injecting to the above controller:

```
mainApp.factory('record',['$http', function($http){ // for delivering records data
    return $http.get('./data/record.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);

mainApp.factory('recordSlides',['$http', function($http){ // for delivering slides on record page
    return $http.get('./data/recordSlides.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);
```

The JSON data from the factory "record" is being pulled and displayed properly but the data from the "recordSlides" factory is not being displayed. It works when I directly pass the json data to "slides" (code Commented out) but when I inject the controller and pass the JSON data through factory it is not working.

this is recordSlides.json:

```
[{
    "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
  },
  {
    "image": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food"
}]
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a service:

```
var deferred = new $q.defer();
$http({...})
.success(function (resp) {
    deferred.resolve(resp);
})
.error(function(err){
    deferred.reject(err); 
}
return deferred.promise;
```

and in controller:

```
record.then(function(data){
    $scope.tracks = data;
});
recordSlides.then(function(data){
    $scope.slides = data;
});
```

Dont forget to include $q dependency in a service

Comment: When I change success() to then() then both of them are not working.

Comment: Sorry, i havent time to write full answer, just tryed to push you in the right direction.. I'll edit it now..

Comment: To work with error, you should add another function in "then" block, separate with ",". It cathces reject object